# Efficient way to iterate through a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that contains several thousand records of company stock data. It contains the following integer fields:

```
low_price, high_price, volume_traded
10, 20, 45667
15, 22, 256565
41, 47, 45645
30, 39, 547343
```

My requirement is to create a new csv file from this data by accumulating the volume_traded at every price level (from low to high). The final result would just be two columns as follows:

```
price, total_volume_traded
10, 45667
11, 45667
12, 45667
....
....
15, 302232
etc
```

In other words the final csv contains one record for every price level (not just the high/low but also the prices in-between), along with the total amount of volume_traded at that price level.

I have got this working however it is terribly slow and inefficient. Im sure there must be better ways of accomplishing this.

Basically what i've done is use nested loops:

- First iterate through each row.
- On each row, create a nested loop to iterate through the price range from low_price to high_price.
- Check if the price already exists in the new dataframe, if so add the current volume_traded to it. If it doesn't exist, apppend the price and volume (ie: create a new row).

Below is some of the relevant code. I would be grateful if anyone could advise a better way of doing this in terms of efficiency/speed:

```
df_exising = #dataframe created from existing csv
df_new = #dataframe for new Price/Volume values

for index, row in df_existing.iterrows():
    price = row['low_price']
    for i in range(row['low_price'], row['high_price']+1):
        volume = row['volume_traded']
        df_new = accumulate_volume(df_new, price, volume)
        price+=1

def accumulate_volume(df_new, price, volume):
    #If price level already exists, add volume to existing
    if df_new['Price'].loc[df_new['Price'] == price].count() > 0:
        df_new['Volume'].loc[df_new['Price'] == price] += volume
        return(df_new)
    else:
        #first occurrence of price level, add new row
        tmp = {'Price':int(price), 'Volume':volume}
        return(df_new.append(tmp, ignore_index=True))

#once the above finishes, df_new is written to the new csv file
```

My guess for why this is so slow is at least partly because 'append' creates a new object every time it's called, and it gets called a LOT. In total, the nested loop from the above code gets run 1595653 times.

I would be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: What's the relevance of iterating over the range `(row['low_price'], row_['high_price'] + 1)`? Doesn't just `df.groupby('low_price')['volume_traded'].sum()` do what you want?

Comment: hi. The data only gives the low_price and high_price for every record. I need every number in between as well. ie: 10, 11, 12, 13 etc. That is why I iterate over every number and assign the relevant volume_traded

Comment: If I understand what you want the following should work: `df.sort(['low_price']).set_index(['low_price']).reindex(index = np.arange(df1['low_price'].min(), df1['low_price'].max()), method='pad')` so this sorts the df by low_price, then sets this to the index, this allows us to reindex using a new index of minn and max value and then filling the missing values

Comment: Why is the high and low price an integer instead of a float?

Comment: @EdChum thank you I think you're onto something. However I get an error: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit. The prices are not going to be unique in the original dataframe. Only once they've been put into the new dataframe will each row be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget a moment about potential issues with methodology (think about how your results would look if 100k shares traded at a price of 50-51 and 100k traded at 50-59).

Below are a set of commented steps that should achieve your goal:

```
# Initialize DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame({'low': [10, 15, 41, 30], 
                   'high': [20, 22, 47, 39], 
                   'volume': [45667, 256565, 45645, 547343]})

# Initialize a price dictionary spanning range of potential prices.
d = {price: 0 for price in range(min(df.low), max(df.high) + 1)}

# Create helper function to add volume to given price bucket.
def add_volume(price_dict, price, volume):
    price_dict[price] += volume

# Use a nested list comprehension to call the function and populate the dictionary.
_ = [[add_volume(d, price, volume) for price in range(low, high + 1)]
      for low, high, volume in zip(df.low, df.high, df.volume)]

# Convert the dictionary to a DataFrame and output to csv.
idx = pd.Index(d.keys(), name='price')
df = pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=idx, columns=['total_volume_traded'])
df.to_csv('output.csv')

>>> df
       total_volume_traded
price                     
10                   45667
11                   45667
12                   45667
13                   45667
14                   45667
15                  302232
16                  302232
17                  302232
18                  302232
19                  302232
20                  302232
21                  256565
22                  256565
23                       0
24                       0
25                       0
26                       0
27                       0
28                       0
29                       0
30                  547343
31                  547343
32                  547343
33                  547343
34                  547343
35                  547343
36                  547343
37                  547343
38                  547343
39                  547343
40                       0
41                   45645
42                   45645
43                   45645
44                   45645
45                   45645
46                   45645
47                   45645
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander your output is exactly what im looking for. However when I run your code the output is not as per yours. Is there something that you perhaps left out of your code when you copied it here? I will update my original question to show you what my output of your code is.

Comment: sorry I just realised I was being stupid. I see your code works I was just printing out the dict,...not iterating through it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would first groupby the 'low_price' column, then sum up the volume_traded, reset the index. This will effectively accumulate all the prices of interest, then you want to sort by the price, this makes the prices monotonic so that we can use it as the index. After setting to be the index we can then call reindex and compute a new index and fill the missing values using `method='pad'`:

```
In [33]:

temp="""low_price,high_price,volume_traded
10,20,45667
15,22,256565
41,47,45645
10,20,12345
30,39,547343"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
df
Out[33]:
   low_price  high_price  volume_traded
0         10          20          45667
1         15          22         256565
2         41          47          45645
3         10          20          12345
4         30          39         547343
In [34]:

df1 = df.groupby('low_price')['volume_traded'].sum().reset_index()
df1
Out[34]:
   low_price  volume_traded
0         10          58012
1         15         256565
2         30         547343
3         41          45645
    In [36]:

df1.sort(['low_price']).set_index(['low_price']).reindex(index = np.arange(df1['low_price'].min(), df1['low_price'].max()+1), method='pad') 
Out[36]:
           volume_traded
low_price               
10                 58012
11                 58012
12                 58012
13                 58012
14                 58012
15                256565
16                256565
17                256565
18                256565
19                256565
20                256565
21                256565
22                256565
23                256565
24                256565
25                256565
26                256565
27                256565
28                256565
29                256565
30                547343
31                547343
32                547343
33                547343
34                547343
35                547343
36                547343
37                547343
38                547343
39                547343
40                547343
41                 45645
```